# Searching MySQL text for specific number using url paramters

Tags: php, mysql, matomo

I have a database like this:

```
id | link                                | someotherstuff
---------------------------------------------------------
1  | index.php?video=123                 | blah
2  | index.php?video=4567&other=variable | blah
3  | site.com/index.php?video=video=1    | blah
```

and so on. 
I would like to use URL parameters to find the right video link.
When I visit: www.mysite.com/index.php?video=1 I want the database to find the "video=1" part of the link column. I have everything working except when searching the link column it  finds both id 1 and id 3 since they both have the number 1 in the link.

I'm using Piwik to get statistics for my pages. I use a session to get the video number from the url and then use this:

```
$videostring = "video%3D".$_SESSION['video']."";
```

with this:

```
$resulting = file_get_contents("http://www.site.com/piwik/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=1&period=range&date=2013-04-05,today&format=php&expanded=1&token_auth=$token_auth&filter_pattern=". $videostring . "");
```

How do I use the filter_pattern so I can limit the search to just the number I want?

Answer (score 0):

```
select id from table where link like '%video=1' OR link like '%video=1?%'
```

With The Edit:

You cannot do that if your server puts % before and after the value of filter_pattern to do filtering.Check for server side code to see what it does to filter_pattern variable just before calling the mysql.

Comment: Thank you for replying but how do I do that? I'm kind of a n00b at this.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no useful way except than using `id` value in your `link` address, like `site.com/index.php?video?video=1&id=3`. So you don't need to search database for finding `id`.it's in your address

Comment: `I use a session to get the video number from the url` . how?

Comment: I start a session and then use $_SESSION['video'] = $_GET['video']

Comment: then my recommend is `UPDATE yourtable SET link=CONCAT(link,'&id=',id)`.Then simply use `$_GET['id']` and you don't need to search your table for getting id

Comment: I know but I have to use the filter_pattern from Piwik. The filter_pattern works like a search engine. You add a word or number that the filter will find in the text column and retreive all the rows that match. if $_GET['id'] is 23 then i'm using "filter_pattern=23" and then it will find everything with 23 in the link. like video=23, video=2323, video=1923, video=723 and so on. just want it to find the exact number I'm searching for.